# Horizontal ProgressBar with start and end position

Tags: android, progress-bar, customization

I have interesting task to achieve. I need to draw progress bar in given range like image shown bellow. Looking on image You can see we have few ranges:

- <0%, 60%)
- <60%, 90%)
- <90%, 100%>

But ranges might be different, and we might have a lot of them. So it have to be generic sollution to draw "progress" on progressbar in given range.

Please note that all other things like: styling progressbar, counting possitions, etc. are not in a scope of this question. I looking for idea only for drawing single progressbar with start and end "drawing percent".

[image]

Comment: Just to understand. What is the sense of a progress bar with a range 60-90? Do you want to update the progress from 60-90 (and outside?)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti As You can see on image, idea is: all that progress bars visually add to 100% and user can more less see what percent have each item on the list.